# "system is computationally singular" error when using `gmm` (GMM Estimation)

Tags: r

Trying to use the GMM package in R to estimate the parameters (a-f) of a linear model:

```
LEV1 = a*Macro + b*Firm + c*Sector + d*qtr + e*fqtr + f*tax
```

Macro, Firm and Sector are matrices with n number of rows. qtr, fqtr and tax are vectors  with n members.

I have one large data frame called unconstrd that has all of the data.  First, I break that data into separate matrices:

```
v_LEV1 <- as.matrix(unconstrd$LEV1)
Macro <- as.matrix(cbind(unconstrd$Agg_Corp_Prof,unconstrd$R1000_TR, unconstrd$CP_Spread))
Firm <- as.matrix(cbind(unconstrd$ppe_ratio, unconstrd$op_inc_ratio_avg, unconstrd$selling_exp_avg,
                  unconstrd$tax_avg, unconstrd$Mark_to_Bk, unconstrd$mc_ratio))
Sector <- as.matrix(cbind(unconstrd$Sect_Flag03,
                  unconstrd$Sect_Flag04, unconstrd$Sect_Flag05, unconstrd$Sect_Flag06,
                  unconstrd$Sect_Flag07, unconstrd$Sect_Flag08, unconstrd$Sect_Flag12,
                  unconstrd$Sect_Flag13, unconstrd$Sect_Flag14, unconstrd$Sect_Flag15,
                  unconstrd$Sect_Flag17))
v_qtr <- as.matrix(unconstrd$qtr)
v_fqtr <- as.matrix(unconstrd$fqtr)
v_tax <- as.matrix(unconstrd$tax_dummy)
```

Then, I bind the data together for the x variable called by gmm:

```
h=cbind(Macro,Firm,Sector,v_qtr, v_fqtr, v_tax)
```

Then, I invoke gmm:

```
gmm1 <- gmm(v_LEV1 ~ Macro + Firm + Sector + v_qtr + v_fqtr + v_tax, x=h)
```

I get the message:

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(hm, xm), crossprod(hm, ym)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.10214e-18
```

I apologize in advance and admit that I'm a neophyte at R and I've never used GMM before.  The GMM function is so general, I've looked at the examples available on the web but nothing seems specific enough to help my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was pretty certain there was no linear dependency between my variables but I went through the exercise of adding one variable at a time to see what was causing the errors.  In the end, I asked a colleague to run GMM on SAS and it ran perfectly, no error messages.  I'm not sure what the problem is with the R version is but at this point I have a solution and give u on GMM on R.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to fit onto a matrix which does not have full rank---try excluding some of the variable and/or look for errors.   We cannot say much more without your data, or at least a sample.

That's more of a modelling question for [Crossvalidated.com](http://crossvalidated.com) than a programming question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Firm is a 108,951x6 matrix with 6 different financial ratios. Macro is 108,951x3 matrix with 3 different macro economic variables, Sector is a 108,951x11 matrix with 11 different sector dummies, v_qtr and v_fqtr are 108,951x1 matrices with 1-4 integers denoting quarters. v_tax is a 108,951x1 matrix which is 1 or 0 depending on whether the data is pre or post the 1986 change in tax code.  v_LEV1 is a 108,951x1 matrix with firm leverage.  Seems there is enough data.  I am able to get a solution using the lm multiple linear regression function.  I don't know what Crossvalidated is..

Comment: Let me be very plain:  Among all your regressors, one or more are linear combinations of other columns, which implies less than full rank.

Comment: It is precisely what the error message is telling you.  Maybe that happens because of the moment conditions in GMM.  Again, without your data we cannot tell.  But the error tells you that you cannot fit what you are trying to fit.

Comment: To put @DirkEddelbuettel's point another way: When you estimate this via `lm()`, are there variables that get dropped from your regression? If so, then those are precisely the variables that are linear combinations of others in your model. `lm()` has no problem with such variables since it contains code that automatically detects such cases. But as soon as you do all this manually, you have to do this yourself, too.

Comment: Come to think of it, the quarter and fiscal quarter variables could be linear combinations of each other.

Comment: Tried rerunning it with just the Macro and Firm variables, getting rid of all of the dummy and quarter variables.  Get the same message with a slightly different reciprocal condition number.  Wondering if there's something larger and more structural that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: We're getting closer :)   I was quite serious when I first suggested to vary variables used...  As for "something larger": can you get  the model matrix and examine it?

Comment: Here are the lm results for just the Macro and Firm variables: Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       2.236e-02  2.668e-02   0.838  0.40196    
Agg_Corp_Prof    -3.470e-09  8.495e-10  -4.086 4.43e-05 ***
R1000_TR          4.774e-02  6.303e-03   7.575 3.90e-14 ***
CP_Spread         3.114e-02  6.146e-03   5.066 4.13e-07 ***

Comment: ppe_ratio         4.237e-01  1.080e-02  39.225  < 2e-16 ***
op_inc_ratio_avg -2.050e-01  1.368e-02 -14.991  < 2e-16 ***
selling_exp_avg  -2.624e-02  4.143e-03  -6.334 2.48e-10 ***
tax_avg          -2.866e+00  2.156e-01 -13.292  < 2e-16 ***
Mark_to_Bk        1.627e-09  2.275e-10   7.152 9.12e-13 ***
mc_ratio         -6.410e-03  1.087e-03  -5.897 3.82e-09 ***

Comment: Sorry. The comment text editor isn't very good.  My point is that, according to lm those macro and firm variables are all significant.

Comment: How about you build up your model variable by variable. Does it work if you include only the macro variables? How about if you include the firm variables as well? And so on. I'm sure you'll eventually get to a variable that 'breaks' the model

Comment: Tried gmm(g = v_LEV1 ~ Macro, x = h) where Macro was just a vector of annual stock market returns and it ran.  Will try building it up one variable by one variable.

Comment: Looks like several of my firm-specific variables are causing singularity problems which I am surprised at.  The ratios are things like sales/total assets, SG&A expense/sales, depreciation/total assets, incomes taxes/total assets.  These ratios should not be linearly dependent.  Anyone have any ideas?